# Ternary states for bool in Go struct (JSON tag)

Tags: json, go, struct

```
type Foo struct {
    ID        string  `json:"id"
    Condition bool    `json:"condition,omitempty"`
}
```

I would like to json.Marshal the `Foo struct` above but the Condition field should have three states. For example if I do the JSON marshaling:

> 1)
>
> ```
> foo := Foo {
>     ID:        "one",
>     Condition: true,
> }
> ```
>
> should turn into json: `{id:"one","condition":true}`
>
> 2)
>
> ```
> foo := Foo {
>     ID:        "two",
>     Condition: false,
> }
> ```
>
> should turn into json: `{id:"two","condition":false}`
>
> 3)
>
> ```
> foo := Foo {
>     ID:        "three",
> }
> ```
>
> should turn into json: `{id:"three"}`

Currently, if I do `2)`, the marshaled json will be `{"id":"two"}` instead of  `{"id":"two,"condition":false}` because the zero value of `bool` is `false`.

One solution is to construct my struct to use the type of `*bool` instead, like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    ID        string  `json:"id"
    Condition *bool   `json:"condition,omitempty"`
}
```

Is that the idiomatic way of differentiating between non-existent bool and false bool in Go?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to do it. And it's not really related to JSON--that's the only way _in Go_ to distinguish between an unset bool, and a false bool.

Comment: One option is to use [https://github.com/guregu/null](https://github.com/guregu/null)

Answer (score 0):

> One solution is to construct my struct to use the type of *bool instead …
> Is that the idiomatic way of differentiating between non-existent bool and false bool in Go?

Yes, that's the idiomatic way to distinguish between not set, true and false.